# Time based rewrites - how to handle two seperate years?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to do rewrites so that the pages:

```
http://www.site.com/page-one
http://www.site.com/page-two
http://www.site.com/page-three
http://www.site.com/page-four
```

Are only available on 25th December 2011 to 31st January 2012

How can I achieve this? I have been playing around with TIME_MON, TIME_DAY, TIME_YEAR and I am getting confused on how it will handle two seperate months, two seperate years, between 25 Dec 2011 to 31 Jan 2012

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} ^2011
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} ^12
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} >24
RewriteRule ^/page-one/?$ /folder/page-one [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-two/?$ /folder/page-two [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-three/?$ /folder/page-three [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-four/?$ /folder/page-four [PT]

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} ^2012
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} ^01
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} >01
RewriteRule ^/page-one/?$ /folder/page-one [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-two/?$ /folder/page-two [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-three/?$ /folder/page-three [PT]
RewriteRule ^/page-four/?$ /folder/page-four [PT]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be more readable, extensible, and it should work ;)

By the way: first thing I've looked is the format:
TIME_MON => current month (0-11)

Thank to [this site here.](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html)

So your rules will never ever work for december ;)

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}/%{TIME_MON}/%{TIME_DAY} 2011/11/(25|26|27|28|29|30|31) [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}/%{TIME_MON}/ 2012/0/
RewriteRule ^/page-(one|two|three)/?$ /folder/page-$1 [NC,QSA,PT]
```

... 3 lines instead of 14 ;)

Tell me if it works.

If it doesn't work: read my usual "two hints", and add the rewrite log in your question.

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)