# Time-Dependent Rewriting and single digit TIME_MON/TIME_DAY variables

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi

I am trying to redirect access to one part of my site before a certain date.  I am using [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) on IIS 6 but I believe ISAPI_Rewrite is compatible with mod_rewrite syntax.  Imagine I wanted to redirect pages to a certain address before the 1st April 2012.  I have found examples where people use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20120401
```

The problem I have is that the server variables for **TIME_MON** and **TIME_DAY** appear to be returning single digits (e.g. 1 rather than 01).

So for the 1st May **%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}** returns **201251** rather than **20120501**.

**201251** is less than **20120401** BUT the first of May is AFTER the first of April.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Time based rewrites - how to handle two seperate years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611381/time-based-rewrites-how-to-handle-two-seperate-years) I have realised that I may be coming at this from the wrong direction.

I think something like the following could work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Someplace/(.*)\.aspx$
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} ^2012
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON}  <4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Someplace/systemdown.html [R=301,L]
```